# Writing Python variable to NetCDF gives TypeError

Tags: python, netcdf, typeerror

I'm trying to write a `Python` variable to a new NetCDF file in Linux.

**Code Excerpt**

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange, dtype
import netCDF4 as nc4
from netCDF4 import Dataset

my_example_nc_file = '/home/user/file1.nc'
nc = Dataset(my_example_nc_file, mode='r')

lons = nc.variables['longitude'][:]
lats = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
data = nc.variables['data'][:]
time = nc.variables['time'][:]

files = file.shape[0]
dims = file.shape[1:]
npy = np.mean(file, axis=0)
nc_dist = np.sort(file.flatten())[::-1]
result = nc_dist[::files]
index = np.argsort(npy.flatten())[::-1]
tmp = np.empty_like(result)
tmp[index] = result
tmp = np.where(npy.flatten() > 0, temp, 0.0)
result_final = tmp.reshape(dims)

# open a new netCDF file for writing.
ncfile = Dataset('/home/user/file2.nc','w') 

# create the x and y dimensions.
ncfile.createDimension('x',lats)
ncfile.createDimension('y',lons)
# create the variable (4 byte integer in this case)
# first argument is name of variable, second is datatype, third is
# a tuple with the names of dimensions.
data = ncfile.createVariable('data',dtype('int32').char,('x','y'))

data[:] = result_final

ncfile.close()
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 120, in <module>
ncfile.createDimension('x',lats)
File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2562, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.createDimension
File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 3364, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension.__init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 4309, in __int__
raise TypeError("Only length-1 arrays can be converted "
TypeError: Only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Does the `x, y` need to be converted to `long, lat`?

Comment: Your question refers to x,y->lon,lat, but the code has x->lat,y->lon

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.Dataset.createDimension): `def createDimension(self, dimname, size=None)`, which means that you need to provide the `size` of each dimension (i.e. `len(lats)`). The variable is normally created next for each dimension with the `lats` array, which I don't see in the example.

Also `y` is latitude and `x` is longitude. Often the variable is created with the dimension order `('y', 'x')` for a 2D array of rows and columns or latitude and longitude.